# MutationObserver in Tampermonkey script always misses the first node

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey, mutation-observers, selectors-api

I have the following `Tampermonkey` custom script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hacker News
// @namespace    https://news.ycombinator.com/*
// @version      2024-02-02
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://news.ycombinator.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    if (mutation.type === "childList" && mutation.addedNodes && mutation.addedNodes.length > 0 && mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      // console.log(`${mutation.addedNodes.length}, ${mutation.type}, ${mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeType}`);
      // console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
      // console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0]);
      Array.from(mutation.addedNodes[0].querySelectorAll('span.titleline')).forEach (element=> {
        console.log(`Matched: ${element.innerText}`);
        element.style.background = 'yellow';
        if (window.webkit) {
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.gotData.postMessage(element.innerText);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(document, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true,
    subtree: true
  }
);
```

It works okay in Chrome but in Firefox, it always misses the first node.

It looks like this in my Firefox plugins:

[image]

Settings look like this. I have set the `Run at:` setting to `document-start` as shown in the 2nd screenshot. First node shouldn't be part of the document at this time from what I understand:

[image]

For some reason, it always misses the first post on the Hacker News page:

[image]

Am I missing something special in Firefox?

**EDIT:**

I have just noticed that when the reload happens, the first node is "escaping" the mutation observer for some reason. I recorded a video of this. It's hard to notice, so you may have to pause the video to look at that frame:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/SUTYwPD.mp4]

I was able to capture a screenshot of that very frame:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/RLNcBB7.png]

Notice how the first node is loaded, rest haven't loaded when MutationObserver kicks in. So the first node escapes it. Why's this? The HTML is rendered server side by Hacker News, so this shouldn't happen from what I understand.

Comment: a) when does the userscript run, i.e. when does the mutationobserver start observing - is the first node already part of the document at that time? b) what do the comment-out logs tell you - in particular the `addedNodes.length` one? c) what's with the `if` statement - are there any calls where the condition does not match?

Comment: @Bergi a) I have set the `Run at:` setting to `document-start` as shown in the 2nd screenshot. First node shouldn't be part of the document at this time from what I understand. b) The commented out logs aren't helping much. I have updated my question towards the end with more details of what I found via video capture. The first node seems to escape the `MutationObserver` for some reason. c) Since my mutation observer is on the `document`, there are many cases when the conditions aren't met. But I think issue is from first node being loaded before mutation observer as per last screenshot.

Comment: @Bergi I think I am facing this issue/bug: https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/211